# ActionResult not being called when using [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor, view, controller

The ActionResult in the controller is not being called. The page is just refreshing.
Check my code below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        @if (@ViewBag.Message != null)
        {
            <p style="color: #b94a48;">@ViewBag.Message</p>
        }    

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)      

        <div class="form-group">

            <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Username</label>
            <div class="input-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>

                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { @placeholder = "Email", @class = "form-control placeholder-no-fix" })

                <p style="color: #b94a48;">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)</p>
            </div>
        </div>    

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Password</label>
            <div class="input-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>    

                @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @placeholder = "Password", @class = "form-control placeholder-no-fix" })

                <p style="color: #b94a48;">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <div>
                <label class="checkbox">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.RememberMe, new { @class = "remember" }) Remember me
                </label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn blue pull-right">
                Login <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i>
            </button>

        </div>

    </fieldset>
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Login(AccountViewModel model, FormCollection args, string ReturnUrl)
{
}
```

RouteConfig:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute("SJSS", "{controller}/Show/{assetCode}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Asset", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
        routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Account", action = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: try input type = submit instead of button type

Comment: tried it but facing the same issue again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try altering your `@Html.BeginForm` to this:

```
@Html.BeginForm("***Action Name***", "***Controller Name***", FormMethod.Post)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be mistaken here but despite the fact that your identation is a bit confusing, I can't find the url which you're posting to, I mean, your form action is empty, even if you submit, how would mvc know which action to call?

Try setting the action and controller parameters on Html.BeginForm.

edit: Check @Roman Denysenko's answer to see an example that might suit your case perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an "Action", "Controller" and "Form method" for your form. See a code below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
}
```